# Any alternative for this 'Where' LINQ query

Tags: c#, .net, linq

i have this linq query. I need to look for any good alternative if possible for this higlighted lambda expression inside Where condition. I was thinking to use coalesce condition ( ?? ) but couldnt make a query.

```
.Where(p => p.Property== null ? true : p.Property.SubPropertyList.Contains(Item))
```

So, I want to get those items from list which has a property null or if not null then satisfies a condition ( `Contains()` )

Comment: Well I'd use `||` instead of a conditional operator here, but beyond that, what are you looking for beyond what you've already got?

Comment: Looking for something like `p.PalletMission?.Destinations.Contains(currentGtpOrder.GtpStation.Node) ?? true` perhaps? Not sure it makes more sense than what you have though.

Comment: How about reversing the condition `.Where(p => p.PalletMission?.Destinations.Contains(currentGtpOrder.GtpStation.Node) != false)` which covers you for both null and true cases

Comment: @JonSkeet yes, but what would you prefer by the way ? 
p.PalletMission == null ? true : p.PalletMission.Destinations.Contains(currentGtpOrder.GtpStation.Node) or
p.PalletMission == null || p.PalletMission.Destinations.Contains(currentGtpOrder.GtpStation.Node)

Wont second one create a null reference exception when property is null when checking the second condition ?

Comment: @InterStellaR if the first expression is true the second expression won't be checked.

Comment: @Charlieface hmm i was trying to use '?' this but i dont know why i had the red line in visual studio that bool cannot be converted to bool?

Comment: @JonSkeet ahh right .. exactly. Sorry for it.

Comment: If you've got working code and want to improve it, then a) you may well want codereview.stackexchange.com; b) you should be very clear about what improvement you're looking for.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you. will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a predicate.
A function that will return `true` of `false`.

In you case:
   `.Where(***p => p.PalletMission == null || p.PalletMission.Destinations.Contains(currentGtpOrder.GtpStation.Node))`

Answer (score 0):

```
 var result = list
            .Where(p =>p.Property == null || p.Property?.SubPropertyList.Contains(1) == true);
```